# Custom Error Handler Providers doesn't seems to be instantiate with --prod flag

Tags: angular, express

I have deployed my angular application on heroku with Express framework.
It works but a custom service which is registered only in production mode
doesn't seems to be instantiate.

The service is correctly instantiate when i use :

```
ng serve // environment.ts with production = true
```

But not when i use :

```
ng serve --prod
-------- or -------
ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false // environment.prod.ts with production = true
node server.js
```

server.js :

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// Send all requests to index.html
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

// default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

core.module.ts :

```
import { errorHandlerProviders } from './error-handlers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    errorHandlerProviders
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ]
})
```

error-handlers/index.ts :

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { UncaugthErrorHandler } from './uncaugth-error.handler';

const errorHandlerProviders = [];

if (environment.production) {
  errorHandlerProviders.push({
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: UncaugthErrorHandler
  });
}

export { errorHandlerProviders };
```

~~Do you have any idea why this is not working ?~~

---

I found the cause of the problem. I have a production configuration in angular.json file which set to true :

- buildOptimizer
- aot (aot compilation)

```
 "configurations": {
            "production": {
              ...
              "aot": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,

            }
          }
```

If i set these properties to false the service UncaugthErrorHandler is correctly injected. I don't understand why aot compilation / build optimization prevents this injection. Moreover performances are downgrade with these properties, does someone understands this behaviour and knows if i could use aot ?